# How can I share a custom URL into a social media button in vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, url, media

I want to share and specific URL via a social media button from my website (let's say a form URL), but can't make it work, only the whatsapp share. I'm using vue2 and running on locale. My main problem is that it shares my localhost URL, not my custom URL. Currently I'm working with the following design of buttons:

```html
<head>
<a
      href="https://wa.me/5211234567890?text=Me%20gustaría%20saber%20el%20precio%20del%20coche"
      class="whatsapp"
      target="_blank"
    >
      <i class="fa fa-whatsapp whatsapp-icon"></i
    ></a>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-skype"></a>
</body>

<style>
 .whatsapp-icon {
    margin-top: 13px;
  }

  .fa {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
  }

  .fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .fa-facebook {
    background: #3b5998;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-twitter {
    background: #55acee;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-linkedin {
    background: #007bb5;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-instagram {
    background: #125688;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-skype {
    background: #00aff0;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `#` in `href="#"`, also you need to put `https://url` for the `#`.

For the example

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/your-name" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook facebook-icon"></i></a>
```